# Unity3d WebGl build size too large

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

The data file generated by unity 3d for webgl is of 136 Mb.
How can i reduce it ?

**Below is the build report :-**

Build Report

Uncompressed usage by category:

Textures      306.5 kb   0.2%

Meshes        283.2 kb   0.2%

Animations    836.9 kb   0.5%

Sounds        0.0 kb     0.0%

Shaders       629.4 kb   0.4%

Other Assets  1.1 mb     0.6%

Levels        2.5 mb     1.5%

Scripts       2.2 mb     1.3%

Included DLLs 5.1 mb     3.1%

File headers  47.1 kb    0.0%

**Complete size 166.7 mb     100.0%**

Textures size is also in kb , so from where this size is getting too large ?
Where should i check ? Please help me.

Comment: https://medium.com/game-development-stuff/how-to-export-your-unity-3d-project-to-webgl-and-keep-a-reasonable-build-size-8f6a719e7c18

Comment: I have tried all the things mentioned on this blog , but no luck.

Comment: In the Player Settings, did you set the compression format to gzip? And disabled any kind of development build in the build setting?

Comment: yes , i tried this also.

Comment: "Textures 306.5 kb" seams unrealisitic, how many texture do you have and what resolution and compression do they have ?

Comment: I have removed all the textures , everything is in assets bundle.

Comment: maybe there are somehow references by a unity scene and end up in the "*.data.unityweb" file. you can open the file in a text editor, maybe you see stuff that should not be in there.

Comment: Now I have reduced complete size to 21.7 mb but still data size is 75 mb , still no luck , can anybody please help.